# Making a method save a UIImage to the photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm attempting to write an application that shows the camera feed, and you can take an image from it. I've successfully set up a UIButton and a linked action method (IBAction) but I'm having trouble making it trigger the UI to save the picture. I have it all set up so when everything goes correctly it should inform the user, but instead it crashes. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
{
    //Start the camera up

    UIImagePickerController *imageViewPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    //Hide default UI elements

    imageViewPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imageViewPickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    imageViewPickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    imageViewPickerController.toolbarHidden = YES;

    //Start the button overlay

    UIView *btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageViewPickerController.view.bounds];
    btnView.opaque = NO;
    btnView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    //Start up the button
    UIButton *snapButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-6, 504, 65, 65)];
    snapButton.alpha = 0.5;
    snapButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(90));
    [snapButton addTarget:snapButton action:@selector(takePhoto:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //Set the button's picture
    UIImage *snapButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"];
    [snapButton setImage:snapButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Add button to the overlay
    [btnView addSubview:snapButton];

    //Overlay button view

    imageViewPickerController.cameraOverlayView = btnView;

    //Fix for iPhone 5 and make fullscreen

    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -55.0);
    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.333333, 1.333333);
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(180));
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
    transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, rotate);
    imageViewPickerController.cameraViewTransform = transform;

    //Let's present it all

    [self presentViewController:imageViewPickerController
                       animated:NO
                     completion:NULL];


}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
    [UIImagePickerController takePicture];
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // Save image
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}


- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    UIAlertView *alert;

    // Unable to save the image
    if (error)
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                           message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album."
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    else // All is well
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                           message:@"Image saved to Photo Album."
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

EDIT: 
Revised code to resolve exception.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
{

    //Start the camera up

    _imageViewPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    //Hide default UI elements

    _imageViewPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _imageViewPickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    _imageViewPickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    _imageViewPickerController.toolbarHidden = YES;

    //Start the button overlay

    UIView *btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_imageViewPickerController.view.bounds];
    btnView.opaque = NO;
    btnView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    //Start up the button
    UIButton *snapButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-6, 504, 65, 65)];
    snapButton.alpha = 0.5;
    snapButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(90));
    [snapButton addTarget:snapButton action:@selector(snapThat) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //Set the button's picture
    UIImage *snapButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"];
    [snapButton setImage:snapButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Add button to the overlay
    [btnView addSubview:snapButton];

    //Overlay button view

    _imageViewPickerController.cameraOverlayView = btnView;

    //Fix for iPhone 5 and make fullscreen

    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -55.0);
    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.333333, 1.333333);
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(180));
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
    transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, rotate);
    _imageViewPickerController.cameraViewTransform = transform;

    //Let's present it all

    [self presentViewController:_imageViewPickerController
                       animated:NO
                     completion:NULL];
}

- (void)snapThat {
    [_imageViewPickerController takePicture];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // Save image
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}


- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
    {
    UIAlertView *alert;

    // Unable to save the image
    if (error)
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                           message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album."
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    else // All is well
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                           message:@"Image saved to Photo Album."
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

EDIT 2: Including headers

```
@interface TurnikitViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *imageView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imageViewPickerController;

@end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Voting on answers to your own question encourages others to pitch in and provide additional assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have this as property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imageViewPickerController;
```

then you init that as you are doing:

```
_imageViewPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

and when you save:

```
[_imageViewPickerController takePicture];
```

Instead now, **you are not calling the method on the instance, but on the class**..that is an error:

```
[UIImagePickerController takePicture];
```

And also, **you are adding as target of your button, itself**..instead the target is `self`:

```
[snapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(snapThat) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. That seems to have done the trick, aside from an exception when the button is pressed. It says that the selector is unrecognized when it is sent from the button to the referencing method. `takePhoto` appears to me like it should reference that method just fine to trigger `takePicture`.

Comment: Also, I did edit my code to call the method on the instance. Is that what the underscore notates? A currently running instance?

Comment: The _var point to your auto synthesized property yes that you have to declare in you header or in your implementation file.

Comment: But I believe I've done this correctly. All my code is correct, so where is this exception coming from?

Comment: edit your post, put one EDIT: at the end and insert all your new code, so i can help you.

Comment: i don't see where you declare your property. I want to see that

Comment: I added in my headers, that should be it

Comment: `-[UIButton snapThat]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16575110`

Comment: edit my answer with the problem solved. But it is clear that you have big gabs on the OOP. This error is clear: doesn't find your selector..your snapThat method. Doesn't find it because you set as target the button, but the button dosnt contains that method. Instead is self the target, that contains that method.